# minimal the function as short as it can be

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I make this Function as short as possible ?

```
 function toggle(id){
        console.log(squares)
        setSquares(prevSquares => {
            const newSquares = [...prevSquares]
            newSquares[id-1].on = !newSquares[id-1].on;
            return newSquares;
        })
    }
```

I have tried to make it minimal and last function that wokred perfect is mentioned below

```
function toggle(id){
        setSquares(prevSquares => {prevSquares[id-1].on = !prevSquares[id-1].on
            return([...prevSquares])
         })
    }
```

I want to know if we can make it even small or not ?

Comment: Smaller doesn't necessarily make it readable.

Comment: please note that `const newSquares = [...prevSquares]` doesn't copy the squares themselves

Comment: You can write `setSquares(squares => squares.map((item, index) => index === id - 1 ? { ...item, on: !item.on } : item))` but can you read that? And is it better than your code?

Comment: Indeed. Making this smaller isnt a good thing to do. Remember your production code will be minified automatically, this kind of change in the src hurts instead of helps by making readability worse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can make your `toggle` function shorter:

```js
const toggle = (id) => {
  setSquares(squares => (
    flipSquareAt(squares, id-1)
  )
};
```

Then somewhere else in the file (or in another file containing all square related functions):

```js
const flipSquareAt = (squares, i) => {
  const result = [...squares];
  result[i] = {...result[i], on: !result[i].on};
  return result;
};
```

It doesn't reduce the total amount of lines in your project, but I don't see why you would want that.

Comment: If you'd do `const flipSquareAt = i => squares => {...}` you could do `setSquares(flipSquareAt(id-1))`

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but given that `setSquares` takes either a function or a value, I think it hurts readability to do it this way, as it is not immediately clear that `flipSquareAt` returns a function.